# recursive function have different result when write-host and save in array

Tags: powershell

I have a problem with the recursive function who get all the parent group of a group recursively.

My function looks like this

```
function Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembershipRecursive ($groupName,$list)
{
  $groupsMembership = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $groupName

  foreach ($groupMembership in $groupsMembership)
  {
    write-host $groupMembership.name
    $list += $groupMembership.name
    Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembershipRecursive -groupName 
    $groupMembership -list $list
  }

  return $list
}
```

when I call my function, I expect that I get the same output on the console and when I echo my list. But the write-host write the things correct, but in the list I get duplicate entry.

Here how I use my function and test

```
$groupsParent = @()
$groupsParent = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembershipRecursive -groupName "g-assistants" -list $groupsParent
write-host "Length" $groupsParent.Length
$groupsParent
```

And I get the following output

```
G-eGR
G-ePA
G-eRPP
G-ePO
HP-Designjet-Z6800ps
G-scan313
Length 27
G-eGR
G-eGR
G-ePA
G-eGR
G-ePA
G-eRPP
G-eGR
G-ePA
G-eRPP
G-ePO    
G-eGR
G-ePA
G-eRPP
G-ePO
HP-Designjet-Z6800ps
G-eGR
G-ePA
G-eRPP
G-ePO
HP-Designjet-Z6800ps
G-scan313
G-eGR
G-ePA
G-eRPP
G-ePO
HP-Designjet-Z6800ps
G-scan313
```

With this exemple group, the group `g-assistants` is in `G-eGR G-ePA G-eRPP G-ePO HP-Designjet-Z6800ps G-scan313`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting duplicate entries in your output because you are passing along the $list in each call; in each iteration you update it and send it along.

You should output from your recursive function information about the group it processed, and in the calling function you should take that output and add it to your list.

I made those changes to your script:

```
function Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembershipRecursive ($groupName)
{
  # Empty list. The current function call knows nothing about who called it
  $list = @()

  # Add the current group to the list
  $list += $groupName

  Write-Host $groupName 

  $groupsMembership = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $groupName

  foreach ($groupMembership in $groupsMembership.Name)
  {
    # Add all child groups to the list
    $list += Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembershipRecursive -groupName $groupMembership
  }

  # Return the current group and all its children
  return  $list
}

$groupsParent = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembershipRecursive -groupName $groupName
write-host "Length" $groupsParent.Length
$groupsParent
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you so much, I understand what was my error. It works perfectly c: